# Function returns empty, print within loop has required output

Tags: python, function

So I have a function that reads takes a dictionary the looks like:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b'], 'c': ['c', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'c']}
```

My function looks like

```
def unioncompare(node, starting):
  visited, stack = set(), [starting]
  while stack:
    vertex = stack.pop()
    if vertex not in visited:
      visited.add(vertex)
      stack.extend(node[vertex])
  return stack
```

And it healthy returns an empty list

However in simple debugging, if I insert a print statement at the second to last line (in the if statement), The iterations produce (roughly) what I'm after

```
 if vertex not in visited:
    visited.add(vertex)
    stack.extend(node[vertex])
    print stack
 return stack

['b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
[]
```

I don't strictly understand what is happening to the values in the if statement that they aren't passed out and returned properly.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: I suspect if you put the `print` inside the loop but outside the `if`, you'll see `stack` grow at first, then shrink down to nothing. Is that not what you want to happen?

Comment: `while stack` without an option to `break` **guarantees** that the function won't return until `stack` is empty.

Comment: did you perhaps want to return visited? rather than stack.

Comment: The shrinking behavior is indeed that, and I think I see why. The visited return will give me the set that the function has been to, where I'm searching for the elements in the dictionary that are accessible from the given input. Given A, A to B, (B as key), B to C (C as key), C to A. If that make sense?

Comment: Thanks to Jonrsharpe! I went thinking about the lack of Break and the growth and shrink. As my list will always reach a certain number, a simple while len(stack) < 3: did the trick to get it exactly where I want. I'm pretty sure this is kind of dirty if it ever was going to take something a bit more variable, but it does the job!